# Get the name of the rows with COUNT in SQL

Tags: mysql

This is my current query:

```
SELECT COUNT(`location`) AS 'amount' FROM offers GROUP BY location;
```

This returns:

[image]

However, I want to be able to attribute each number to the value. For example, it would output:

[image][image]

Basically, group

```
SELECT COUNT(`location`) AS 'amount' FROM offers GROUP BY location;
```

and

```
SELECT location FROM offers GROUP BY location;
```

into one query

Comment: `Select location, count(location)  as amount from offers group by location `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT location, COUNT(location) AS amount
FROM offers
GROUP BY location
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`select location,count(*) As amount from  offers group by location;`